# Tensorflow.js create model from downloaded file

Tags: tensorflow.js

I have a trained model, saved it with `const saveResult = await model.save('localstorage://my-model-1');`.

Now I want to reload it and use it again. So I want to do something like this:

```
async function loadModel() {
    let myModel = tf.sequential();
    myModel = await model.save('downloads://my-model-1')
    console.log(myModel);

    let outputs = myModel.predict([
        tf.tensor2d([[0, 0, 1]])
    ]);
    outputs.print();
}
```

But It seems like model.save returns a `modelArtifactsInfo`. So how could I create a model from this Object?

I followed [this tutorial](https://js.tensorflow.org/tutorials/model-save-load.html) but they don't really explain that.

is that even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the tutorial it says it all:

You just have to call `tf.loadModel` with your savehandle which returns a promise which resolves to the loaded model or throws an error. In your case the handle would be `'localstorage://my-model-1'`.

```
const model = await tf.loadModel('localstorage://my-model-1');
```

Comment: Oh damn I could have sworn I have tried that. Anyways Thank you!